# Issue While creating function in PostgreSQL "ERROR: syntax error at or near "ROWTYPE""

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Below is a simple procedure in PL/SQL

```
PROCEDURE emp_get_rec (emp_rec IN OUT NOCOPY emp_content%ROWTYPE)
  IS
    v_cnt   NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_cnt
    FROM emp_content
    WHERE emp_id = emp_rec.emp_id;
    IF v_cnt = 1
    THEN
      SELECT * INTO emp_rec
      FROM emp_content
      WHERE emp_id = emp_rec.emp_id;
    END IF;
 END emp_get_rec;
```

Which I am trying to convert in PostgreSQL,

```
Create or replace function emp_get_rec (emp_rec IN OUT emp_content%ROWTYPE)
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    v_cnt   NUMBER;
BEGIN

       SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_cnt
    FROM emp_content
    WHERE emp_id = emp_rec.emp_id;
    IF v_cnt = 1
    THEN
      SELECT * INTO emp_rec
      FROM emp_content
      WHERE emp_id = emp_rec.emp_id;
    END IF;
 END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I am facing following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ROWTYPE"

Comment: If you have error "at or near "ROWTYPE"" then just remove `%ROWTYPE` (including percent sign) :o) In PostgreSQL table/view names could be used as  type names as is, without any additions.

Comment: Abeslisto, the parameter is of in and out type. I need to call this particular function via other function which passes its complete record. So inoder to provide complete set of row %ROWTYPE has to be used. So if you can share some syntax for the same.

Comment: What Abelisto is trying to say: the `%ROWTYPE` is **not** needed in Postgres. You can use the table name as a "data type" and pass the complete record to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html):

> Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically created, with the same name as the table, to represent the table's row type.

So you are able to use the table name as the type name where syntactically it means a type:

```
create or replace function emp_get_rec (emp_rec IN OUT emp_content)
```